# Two SharePoint server Farms using different configuration databases with same content DB's

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007

I am having strange problem while cloning the environments for SharePoint 2007 farm. We cloned the WFE and DB servers with different names. When the configuration wizard has run pointing to the new DB server for complete the new FARM, The config is pointed to the new Database server but the content databases remains same as old. This makes the production and cloned sites pointed to the same content.

How can this be possible to have a SharePoint farms with separate config DB's and same content DB's. Please advise and now the search service in the production is also broken.

Comment: would ask how you clone the Farms, did you build two farms separate or what?

Comment: yes its a closed VM's separately but different names and IP's

Comment: Afik...you can't clone the sharepoint VM...you have to build 2nd farm n run the configuration wizard n create config db....then you have to copy the content db over there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just try to focus on one of the cloned server. Remove the content db from sharepoint, rename the content DB or whatsoever (just to see that the connection is correctly pointed to the right server), and then re-add it back, notice that new content db added should be with the new name.

If you remember, there's possibility and feature for us to add content database from a different database SQL server or different instance. And connection settings might be saved on this point.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825314.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would shut the cloned VM farm down ASAP, or you potentially risk causing more problems in your production farm.  The only way you could potentially pull this off is if you had the new farm on an isolated network segment away from your production farm.  Then, you could leave the host names the same.  Otherwise, you need to build the 2nd farm from scratch.

When you first started your cloned farm, it probably made some connections back to your original production DB server and your original WFE servers.  Did you remove the old WFEs from the farm and re-add the new cloned VM WFE's?

Comment: one thing...you cannot restore / clone config db...if you tried but its not supported at all from MSFT.

Comment: The only use case I would even consider it for would be on an isolated test/dev network.  Of course, the best option is to just rebuild the farm.

Comment: @tyshock: I have  removed the newly cloned farm from the prodcution environment. I am also planning to rerun the configuration wizard to establish the old WFE back to the fam and fix the broken search. Any thoughts please let me know.